# Fancy pop-up won't work with-in toggel div

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, toggleclass

II'm currently working on a website that works with a toggle menu. I've placed a fancybox within a toggle menu item, now when a thumbnail is 'clicked on' it won't open the big image with a normal popup but opens in a new browserframe. Is there a fix for this bug?

Here's the html.

```
<div class="slide02"><h4>heading</h4></div>
<div class="view02">
<div class="tekstblok" style="width:500px;"><p>just some more tekst</p></div>
<div class="#blok1">
<div id="#blok" style="width:175px;">
<p><a id="1" href="#" target="_blank" title="Totaal overzicht Timeline sectie 1"><imagelink alt="" src="#" /></a></p>
```

I've used the show_hide_expand_collapse_javascript script from alohatechsupport webdesignmaui

Comment: you need to provide more code than that, your js that triggers fancybox and what selector is bound to it. Also, what version of fancybox are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, i figured it out. Had 2 scriptlines in head sections that pointed at 2 simular jquery script (one for toggle menu and one for fancy) they worked agianst each other, deleted one of them and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

When using something like FancyBox, your hyperlink's "href" atrribute shows the element to be shown

```
<a href="#some">click me</a>
<div id="some">text</div>
```

if you want to show element with "some" in your fancybox

Comment: I believe down votes should be commented in order to show why the answer is wrong

Comment: I don't think that is a valid value for the `target` attribute or the way fancybox works neither. The OP is not clear whether if he wants to open `div#blok1` in fancybox or not.

Comment: It is clearly written "if you want to show div#blok1". It should be enough to understand that it will show blok#1 not something else

Comment: additionally, the link with `target` attribute is a `children` of the `div#blok1` ... so this is maybe why the answer is down voted.

Comment: Again, it is clearly written "if you want to show div#blok1", JFK.

Comment: well, it seems to me that you don't understand how fancybox works and how selectors should be bound to it and how you can fire fancybox from a link ... and definitively is not through the `target` attribute. Your answer doesn't provide a fix and is misleading.

Comment: You're right, JFK. It should be "href" attribute. Thanks for the comment! I really was blinded for a while :)